# Bind excel file data with TFS

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel, tfs

I am new to TFS and I have a requirement that I have to bind my excel file to TFS server.I am using excel 2013 and TFS 2010 My requirements are like this:

1. Excel file can contain any data and it should be stored at TFS server.
2. Excel file should be accessible to all the TFS users.
3. Every user should be able to get excel from TFS server locally and if makes some changes, should be able to checkin those changes.
4. Excel file should be accessible without using visual studio.

Is it possible to do some thing like this. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of TFS 2010, you may try to use [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs), first 5 users in your team are FREE.
2. TFS supports version controlled Microsoft Office files, you can add your Excel file into TFS. TFS won't change anything to the content in Excel file, just control the version of Excel file.
3. Just treat Excel file as a normal file, you can manage your Users permission to control who can access this file. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477(v=vs.100).aspx
4. If you don't want to view the file in VS, you can view it on Web Access. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523998(v=vs.100).aspx
5. If you insist to use on-premise TFS, you may consider integrating SharePoint product with TFS. This integration includes the option to create a website, referred to as a team project portal, for each team project. Teams can use this portal to share process guidance, project documents, templates, and reports according to each team member's role in the project. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253177(v=vs.100).aspx